# Find an HTML element next to specific closing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm looking to see if the last `<hr>` tag within the parent `<main>` exists directly before the closing `</main>` tag.

So in the following, the `<hr>` tag that is last within the `<main>` tag, directly before a closing `</main>` tag is the one targeted:

```
<main>
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
  </div>
  <hr class="container" />
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
  </div>
  <hr class="container" />
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  </div>
  <hr class="container" />
</main>
```

Although the `<hr>` should not be removed if, for example, there is a `<div>` tag in front of it:

```
<main>
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
  </div>
  <hr class="container" />
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
  </div>
  <hr class="container" />
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: So, unfortunately @Sirko answered already, but we generally like users to show some effort towards a solution themselves.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I can appreciate that. I was attempting to initially go a pure JS route and unfortunately overcomplicating the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the HR elements based on whether or not they are the last child of the same parent

```
$('hr').filter(function() {
    return this === this.parentNode.lastElementChild;
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3j3md9wj/)

Or target any HR elements that are also the last child

```
$('main hr:last-child').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can get the last element within the `main`, check if it's a `hr`, and remove it if so:

```js
var $last = $('main :last');
if ($last.is('hr'))
    $last.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
  </div>
  <hr class="container" />
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
  </div>
  <hr class="container" />
  <div>
     lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
     lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  </div>
  <hr class="container" />
</main>
```

Here's a working jsFiddle as SO snippets are still broken:

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/45uqcLqp/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$('main hr:last').next().length) // checks if there is a next html element (sibling ) after the last hr tag.
   $('main hr:last').remove();
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/zmb79f3a/1/

Answer (score 0):

jQuqery solution comes down to getting the selector right:

```
if( $( 'main .container:last-child' ).length > 0 ){
  // do your stuff 
}
```